# Issue with Azure Data Factory - Long file path names

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using copy activity to copy the files from on premise to Azure Storage Account . The job is failing as there is a long file path name at the source.
can someone help me how can i fix this issue
I am getting the following error

```
 "errorCode": "2200",
 "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorFileNotFound,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot find the file specified. Folder path: '<<long file path>>''.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Message=Could not find file '<<long file path>>'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "CopyToBlob",
    "details": []
```

Comment: Did you try rename it with a short name/path?

Comment: can you please explain me a bit in detail. I didn't get you. Are you saying t rename the files ?

Comment: yeah, maybe there are some files with long names.

Comment: Renaming would work, but i have a big data source to copy (approx 50k files) and its in folders, subfolders and we get this big data source every week. so i dont want to manually update them every time.

Comment: Can you try to using foreach active to upload the files?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a limitation on the file path maximum length which is already documented in below documentation :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation

Could you please follow these steps to enable long path in you SHIR hosted VM and see if that helps to resolve the issue (This workaround is suggested for the OS of the VM where SHIR installed is at-least Windows Server 2016, Windows 10):

1. Logon to SHIR hosted VM.
2. Open "Local Group Policy Editor", in the left-handed pane, drill down to computer configuration > Administrative Templates > system > Filesystem.
   On the right, find the "Enable win32 long paths" item and double-check it.
3. In the properties window that opens, select the "Enabled" option and then click "OK".

   [image]
4. You can now exit the Local Group Policy Editor and restart your computer (or sign out and back in) to allow the changes to finish.